# How to manually close connection to database and cancel querying data running in background process?

Tags: c#, oracle, backgroundworker

I have Windows Forms application that connects to Oracle database using a `BackgrwoundWorker`.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form, IDataFetcher
{
    public EntryForm EntryForm { get; set; }
    public ApplicationSettings Settings { get; set; }

    private DbDataBackgroundWorker BackgroundWorker { get; set; }

    enum QueryStatus { RUNNING, NOT_STARTED }

    private QueryStatus;
    


    public BillingForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        // configure background actual opearations
        BackgroundWorker = new OpearationBackgroundWorker()
        {
            OnDataFetch = OnDataFetch,
            OnDataFetchCompleted = OnDataFetchCompleted
        };
    }



    public BillingForm(EntryForm parentForm, ApplicationSettings appSettings) : this()
    {
        EntryForm = parentForm;
        Settings = appSettings;
        queryStatus = QueryStatus.NOT_STARTED;
    }



    private void ExecuteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        switch (queryStatus)
        {
            case QueryStatus.NOT_STARTED:
                BackgroundWorker.Start();
                break;

            case QueryStatus.RUNNING:
                BackgroundWorker.Stop();
                break;
        }
    }

    

    public void OnDataFetchCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        queryStatus = QueryStatus.NOT_STARTED;
    
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message, Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }


    public void OnDataFetch(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        if (worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            //MessageBox.Show("Запрос остановлен");
            return;
        }


        // create database handler
        var db = new DatabaseConnector(Settings.DbConnectionString);


        var model = new BillingModel(db)
        {
            PostTitle = PostTitle,
            StartDate    = StartDateTimePicker.Value,
            EndDate      = EndDateTimePicker.Value,
        };


        try
        {
            
            model.Query((datatable) =>
            {
                Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {

                    QueryResultDataGridView.DataSource = null;

                    QueryResultDataGridView.DataSource = datatable;
                    
                }));
            });

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Invoke(new Action(() => {

                queryStatus = QueryStatus.NOT_STARTED;
            }));
        }

    }
}
```

When I click on "Start" button (method `ExecuteButton_Click`) program fetches data in background and put them into a `DataGridView`.

```
// this class starts operations in background
public class OpearationBackgroundWorker
{

    public Action<object,DoWorkEventArgs> OnDataFetch { get; set; }
    public Action<object, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs> OnDataFetchCompleted { get; set; }
    //public Action<object, ProgressChangedEventArgs> OnDataFetchProgress { get; set; }

    private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker()
    {
        WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
    };

    public void Start()
    {
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(OnDataFetch);
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(OnDataFetchCompleted);

        if ( !backgroundWorker.IsBusy )
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        else
            throw new Exception("Process running!");
    }


    public void Stop()
    {
        backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
        backgroundWorker.Dispose();
    }
}



public class SimpleModel : AbstractModel
{
    public IDatabaseFetcher Db { get; set; }

    public string PostTitle { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }



    public BillingModel(IDatabaseFetcher db)
    {
        Db = db;
    }


    public override void Query(Action<DataTable> callback)
    {
        var query = "SELECT  * FROM posts WHERE post_titile = " + PostTitle;

        Db.Query = query;
        Db.Fetch(data => callback(data));
    }
}
```

The program uses C# `using` construct to automatically handle the database connection.

```
public interface IDataFetcher
{
    void OnDataFetch(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e);
    void OnDataFetchCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e);
}


class DatabaseConnector : IDatabaseFetcher
{

    private string connectionString = "";

    public string Query { get; set; }


    public DatabaseConnector(string connectionString)
    {
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
    }


    // here i query data from db
    public void Fetch(Action<DataTable> action)
    {
        using (var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        using (var cmd = new OracleCommand(Query, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (!reader.HasRows)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Empty result!");
                }

                var dataTable = new DataTable();
                dataTable.Load(reader);

                // run callback processor
                action(dataTable);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But now, I want to slightly change the program's behaviour and add the ability manually cancel an operation, and close the connection to the database.

I already know how to cancel the `BackgrwoundWorker` execution, but I can't find solution for how to manually close connection to database and cancel querying of data running in a background process, when user clicks on the "Stop" button.

How to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using the `.Close()` method on the DB object?

Comment: Where should I call this method? In BackgroundWorker__DoWork Method when check the CancelationPending property?

Comment: Possibly! We have no way of answering without any associated code being posted. Would you mind updating your post with the associated code so we can better assist you?

Comment: Ok. I'll update post with actual code, but unfortunatly, only tomorrow. Thank you, for you response!

Comment: Instead of the ancient `BackgroundWorker` use `async/await` and pass a `CancellationToken` all the way down, then you can cancel it very easily